# Question about changing parameter value in Swift

Tags: swift

I am working on a POST request with application / x-www-form-urlencoded. There is a question in the process of specifying parameters to be passed using Alamofire.

I created a parameter variable called `passingParameter`
I want to change the parameter at the time the user_id was created.

```
var passingParameter = [
        "user_id" : "null",
        "user_email" : "null",
        "user_age" : "null",
        "user_gender" : "null",
        "user_birthday" : "null",
        "user_type" : "google"
    ]
```

How do I put an id in the `passingParameter` variable?

ex)

```
var passingParameter = [
        "user_id" : "1122445566",
        "user_email" : "null",
        "user_age" : "null",
        "user_gender" : "null",
        "user_birthday" : "null",
        "user_type" : "google"
    ]
```

Comment: Do you know how to use dictionaries? `passingParameter` is basically a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what's being asked here.

If you already have the variable of `user_id` somewhere, let's say like

```
var userID = "1122445566"
```

Then you can simply assign the value at creation.

```
var passingParameter = [
        "user_id" : userID,
        "user_email" : "null",
        "user_age" : "null",
        "user_gender" : "null",
        "user_birthday" : "null",
        "user_type" : "google"
    ]
```

or later like

```
passingParameter["user_id"] = userID
```